# What Stack Exchange domain names do I need to white-list to handle smooth login credential transfer?

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts, firefox

I use Firefox to log into my Stack Exchange account(s) and the login handover between Exchanges works well - for vanilla Firefox.

A while back, I installed the [Self-Destructing Cookies](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/) add-on for Firefox. (An absolutely *superb* plugin, I highly recommended it).

For sites that pass credential cookies between affiliated domain/sites (and where I want this to happen), I usually just add the applicable domains to the plugin's whitelist, after examining the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) log.

However I can't seem to cover the whole chain involved in an inter-Exchange login handover. I currently have `stackexchange.com`, `openid.stackexchange.com` and my topic specific exchange domains white-listed. But I get asked for login credentials. Oddly enough if I back-navigate then forward-navigate from that screen I'll be logged in from cookies correctly.

This behaviour can be pretty easy reproduced with a Firefox browser with Self-Destructing Cookies add-on installed (and any cookie manager add-on for easier cache control).

Comment: sstatic.net also

Comment: @lostsock Is that a stack exhange specific site?

Comment: @LateralFractal That domain is Stack Exchange's static content delivery network. [See its homepage.](http://sstatic.net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you'll want stackexchange.com, openid.stackexchange.com (assuming you use that), stackoverflow.com (and any other custom-domain sites of ours you may be logging into), stackauth.com, sstatic.net.

I *think* that should do it, but keep in mind that this list may change at any time and we don't intentionally support browser addons, so you set all this up essentially at your own risk.